# Связь между контейнерами Docker в разных сетях

Tags: сеть, docker, docker-compose

Есть два контейнера, mysql использует network_mode: host, а phpmyadmin использует сеть reverse-proxy (bridge)
При попытке войти на в phpmyadmin, выдает ошибку **"mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused"**

Если в mysql изменить сеть на peverse-proxy все работает, но этот вариант не подходит.

Как решить проблему?

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:

  service:
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: Test
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
    image: mysql:8.0.21
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/mysql
    working_dir: /var/lib/mysql

version: '3.8'

volumes:

  data:
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
networks:
  default:
  reverse-proxy:
    external: true

services:

  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: Test
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
      PMA_HOST: localhost
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
    networks:
      reverse-proxy:
        aliases:
          - phpmyadmin

version: "3.8"
```

Comment: При использовании сетевого режима host контейнер (с сетевой точки зрения) работает как приложение, запущенное без контейнера. Поэтому чтобы достучаться до БД в таком режиме нужно обратиться на хост, где этот контейнер запущен. Тем не менее, я бы не рекомендовал оставлять это так, наверняка есть вариант лучше. Объясните зачем у Вас БД работает в таком режиме? И почему БД в сети с PMA не вариант?

Comment: На работе так устроенно что БД в режиме host, а все другие проекты которые используют эту БД в отдельной сети